# Batch file to unzip with 7-zip and then move the zip files to a different folder after the unzip completes

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will unzip files in a folder using 7-zip and then once the files have been unzipped, moved the zip files to a different folder.

So far, I have a batch file that does the following.

```
7z.exe x q:\*.zip -op:\
move q:\*.zip q:\Completed
```

I don't want the move feature to work until after the zip process completes.

Comment: Not sure if that is what you need, but have you tried `start /wait 7z.exe x q:\*.zip -op:\`? That should start the unzipping and wait until it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances that should be the case. If some zip's might be added to q: while moving it gets difficult.

To have better control you should use a for to unzip single zips and move only if successful.

```
@Echo off
Pushd q:\
For %%A in (*.zip) Do 7z.exe x -op:\ "%%A" && Move "%%A" q:\completed
popd
```

This may be a bit slower.